# retrieving array value having symbol as object using foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I would like to retrieve the field names in the database, one of which named `'wardno/houseno'`. When i tried to retrieve it as object using `foreach` i'm getting

My code,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_application');
$this->db->where('app_no', '1/ML/201314/TVM');
$q=$this->db->get();
foreach($q->result() as $row) 
echo $row->wardno/houseno;
```

The error shows,

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$wardno
Filename: controllers/admin_sona.php
Line Number: 19

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant houseno - assumed 'houseno'
Filename: controllers/admin_sona.php
Line Number: 19

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Division by zero
Filename: controllers/admin_sona.php
Line Number: 19
```

Is it possible to retrieve the database value with symbol as object?

Comment: Try like `echo $row->wardno;echo $row->houseno;`

Comment: Using slash in your column name is not a formal one. try to replace '/' with underscore'_'. Then try running your code.

Comment: Yes.. @user3017264 using slashes in fieldnames is not a standard. May be changing to '_' is the best and standard way.

Comment: @user3017264 : If you have got a solution, let us know.. would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to give

```
foreach($q->result_array() as $row) 
  echo $row['wardno/houseno'];// or even echo $row['wardno\/houseno'];
```

instead of

```
foreach($q->result() as $row) 
  echo $row->wardno/houseno;
```

Give it a try!

----EDIT------

As you dont want it to be converted into an array, try

```
echo $row[17]; //Just try. I am not sure where it hurts the code. In case of error, let me know in comments
```

Comment: Can you printr($row) and get me the result of the first row alone? may be you can access like by giving the index. strictly of example: $row[0] That too is a try.!

Comment: Yup! Here goes that,    
stdClass Object ( [app_id] => 2 [app_no] => 1/ML/201314/TVM [office_code] => TVM [category] => SC [loan_id] => 5 [app_name] => Manu K [app_photo] => b17916f172f50e0861392a0c486a924b.png [app_sign] => d3d339edec46c4418f9eaaf9b65fcd3f.jpg [dob] => 2013-12-18 [gender] => Male [StateCd] => 18 [DistCd] => 1 [lbtype] => P [lbcd] => 51 [villageCd] => 3 [talukCd] => 3 [wardno/houseno] => A41(12/1234) [housename] => Sreenilayam [ipaddress] => 10.162.21.14 [app_status] => 1 )

Comment: try echo $row[17]; Again.. just a try. I changed 16 to 17.. sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
$row->wardno
```

to this:

```
$row['wardno']
```

Same thing for houseno

```
$row['houseno']
```

don't know if you have afield named `wardno/houseno` inside your database, I thinked that you have two different fields. If is the same field I advise you to use `_` instead of `/` inside your database.

If is the same field try this:

```
echo $row['wardno/houseno'];
```

to convert array to object try this:

```
function arrayToObject($array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return $array;
    }

    $object = new stdClass();
    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {
            $name = strtolower(trim($name));
            if (!empty($name)) {
                $object->$name = arrayToObject($value);
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

$arr = arrayToObject($your_array);
```

Comment: k, i replaced '/' in the field name with '_'

Comment: Perfect. I have added a function to convert array into object @user3017264

Comment: Yeah thats a way you can do by converting array back to an object.. or you can alternatively use something like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php) Eg #5, #6, #7